# How do I solve this vector equation algebraically?

Tags: vectors

The question wants to solve the equation is $\textbf{x} \times \textbf{r} + \lambda\textbf{r} = \textbf{y}$ for **r**. I have tried to solve the equation using triple scalar product, but got stuck instead..

My thought process:

1. Perform cross product of x on both sides. This will cancel out the term $\textbf{x} \times \textbf{r}$ and result in $\textbf{x} \times \lambda\textbf{r} = \textbf{x} \times \textbf{y}.$
2. By observation, **r** must be equal to $\frac{\textbf{y}}{{\lambda}}$.

However, this is not the answer. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: $\textbf{x} \times  (\textbf{x} \times \textbf{r})$ is not zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(\textbf{x} \times \textbf{r} + \lambda\textbf{r}) \cdot \textbf{x} = \textbf{y} \cdot \textbf{x} $$
$$\lambda\textbf{r} \cdot \textbf{x} = \textbf{y} \cdot \textbf{x} $$ 
$$\textbf{x} \times  (\textbf{x} \times \textbf{r})  + \lambda \textbf x \times \textbf{r} = \textbf x \times\textbf{y}$$
$$-(\textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{x}) \textbf{r} +(\textbf{x} \cdot\textbf{r})  \textbf{x} +\lambda \textbf x \times \textbf{r} = \textbf x \times\textbf{y}$$

$$-(\textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{x}) \textbf{r} +(\frac{\textbf{x} \cdot\textbf{y}}{\lambda})   \textbf{x} +\lambda (\textbf{y}-\lambda\textbf{r}) = \textbf x \times\textbf{y}$$
Now solve for $\textbf{r}$

Comment: For $\lambda=0$ the solution is a bit different. I have solved it there : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283651/find-vec-r-if-vec-r-times-vec-a-vec-b/2283731#2283731

Answer (score 0):

You can't deduce from $\mathbf{x}\times\lambda\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{y}$ that $\lambda\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{y}$. Besides (as you were told in the comments), $\mathbf{x}\times(\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{r})$ is not $0$ in general.

Why don't you solve the system$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)\times(r_1,r_2,r_3)+\lambda(r_1,r_2,r_3)=(y_1,y_2,y_3)?$$It's just a system of three linear equations in three unkonwns. The solution is:\begin{align}r_1&=\frac{-{x_1}^2y_1-x_1x_2y_2-x_1x_3y_3-\lambda x_3y_2+\lambda x_2y_3-\lambda^2y_1}{\lambda({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2+\lambda^2)}\\r_2&=\frac{-x_1x_2y_1-{x_2}^2y_2-x_2x_3y_3+\lambda x_3y_1-\lambda x_1y_3-\lambda^2y_2}{\lambda({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2+\lambda^2)}\\r_3&=\frac{-x_1x_3y_1-x_2x_3y_2-{x_3}^2y_3-\lambda x_2y_1+\lambda x_1y_2-\lambda^2y_3}{\lambda({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2+\lambda^2)}.\end{align}